# Hypothetical sentence about Superman

Tags: word-usage

> Would Superman be such a great lad if he **had been** born on Earth?

Can we write this sentence this way? Like imagining how Superman would be if he was an earthling.

Specifically, I want to know if "had been" is the correct verb to write.

Comment: A past conditional here is correct.

Answer (score 1):

This is fine / normal usage.

You could certainly write it many other ways, if you want to be more verbose/flowery, but as a whole this is absolutely 'common usage'.